# SQL Track Open Appointment

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner of SQL, I am working on a query that generates the Open Appointment Time Slot for each Provider (Employee). Can anyone help to with the following query? Thank you very much!

Schedule table sample Data:

```
ScheduleNum |  ProvNum (Provider) | SchedDate | StartTime | EndTime
          1 |                   3 |  7/1/2017 |    8:00AM |  9:00 AM
          2 |                   3 |  7/1/2017 |   10:00AM | 11:00 AM
          3 |                   4 |  7/1/2017 |    8:00AM |  9:00 AM
          4 |                   4 |  7/1/2017 |   12:00PM |  1:00 PM
          5 |                   4 |  7/1/2017 |    3:00PM |  4:00 PM
```

Open Appointment Query Table Expected Result:

```
ProvNum (Provider) | SchedDate | avail_start_dt_time| avail_end_dt_time
                 3 | 7/1/2017  |            9:00 AM |          10:00 AM
                 4 | 7/1/2017  |            9:00 AM |          12:00 PM
                 4 | 7/1/2017  |            1:00 PM |           3:00 PM
```

Query that I am working on.

```
SELECT
    avail.schedulenum
  , avail.provnum
  , avail.start_at  as avail_start_dt_time
  , avail.end_at    as avail_end_dt_time
  , avail.on_dt     as just_date_no_time
  , avail.starttime as prov_start_time
  , avail.endtime   as prov_end_time
FROM (
  SELECT
        dts.num, dts.on_dt, dts.start_at, dts.end_at, s.provnum, s.starttime, s.stoptime
  FROM (
        /* generates 1000, 10 minute "slots", starting at a variable date */
        SELECT
              schedulenum + 1 as num
            , DATE_ADD(INTERVAL (slots.num * 10) MINUTE) start_at
            , DATE_ADD(INTERVAL ((slots.num+ 1) * 10) MINUTE) end_at
        FROM (
              /* generates 1000 rows 0 to 999 */
              SELECT hundreds.digit * 100 + tens.digit * 10 + ones.digit AS num
              FROM (
                    SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                   ) ones
              CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                         ) tens
              CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                         ) hundreds
              ) slots
        ) dts
  INNER JOIN schedule s ON s.starttime < dts.end_at AND s.stoptime > dts.start_at
  ) avail
WHERE schedulenum IS NULL
```

Comment: Good, but see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your expected output really throws a wrench into things.  Do you really need to have the result as available ranges, rather than in another format, such as a list of available one hour blocks?

Comment: Ideally, I would like a list of available half hour blocks, but some of the appointment starts at 9:10 AM, as some of the customers are just scheduled to get something quick. @TimBiegeleisen, do you have some advice for me?

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for the edit!

Comment: If you join a calendar table consisting of 30 minute blocks across each date, then your problem becomes much easier, and your many line query can be reduced to just 5-10 lines.  But the problem of appointments starting at arbitrary times is a tricky one.,

Comment: Yes, that is my struggling part in here, as the appointment starting time is not in a routine, it can be 9:10, 9:45. And it would look like a mess if I set it to every 5 or every 10 mins blocks.